# Why is Newtonian gravity linear and independent on the presence of other bodies?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy, linear-systems

I have read somewhere that gravitational fore is linear and does not depend on the presence of other bodies around it, what does that mean?

> Another important characteristic of gravity is that it is "linear". That means that the gravitational force exerted by any body on any other body does not depend on the presence of other bodies, and the forces they exert. In the basic formula
> $$\vec{g}_{12} = - G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r^2}\hat{r},$$
> expressing the magnitude of the force between particles 1 and 2, and
> $$v_{12} = - G \frac{m_1 m_2}{r},$$
> expressing their potential, there is no reference to any other particles.
>
> For these two reasons, we can calculate the potential energy of the specified, or any other, configuration by considering any procedure we choose by which the particles might be moved into that configuration, starting from a reference position at which the potential is defined to be 0 (zero).

Can someone explain me what it is exactly saying?

Comment: "I have read somewhere that gravitational fore is linear and does not depend on the presence of other bodies around it, what does that mean?" Where did you read this. Please cite an accessible reference so that we can see the statement in context.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Certainly the gravitational force that one body exerts on another is independent of the presence of other bodies. But by superposition, the total gravitational force exerted on any given body is the vector sum of the gravitational forces caused by the presence of all the other bodies.

Comment: Did you see the part that begins "That means that...."?

Answer (score 3):

Linearity essentially means that the field does not interact with itself. To give a counter-example, it is interesting to look at a nonlinear theory of gravity, such as General Relativity (which has the Newtonian theory as a limiting case).

In General Relativity, gravity is not generated only by masses, but rather by any form of energy (masses being a particular case). As a consequence, gravitational potential energy$^1$ also generated gravity, i.e., regions with a lot of gravitational potential energy induce even more gravity, and the effect keeps repeating itself. This means the dynamics of the gravitational field is quite complicated: if you were to compute the gravitational field of the Sun using General Relativity, you'd have to consider also the gravitational effects due to the presence of gravity itself.

Now suppose you were able to compute the gravitational field of the Sun and of the Earth. If you wanted to obtain the total gravitational field due to both, you'd not be allowed to simply sum them: the sum has a greater amount of potential energy, which means it has even more gravity which you did not account for. Your calculation is incomplete. That is one of the reasons General Relativity is complicated.

What your text is saying is that this does not happen in Newtonian theory. Gravity does not interact with itself. You can compute the gravitational field of a particle by just considering the particle alone and, if you want to compute the gravitational field of a bunch of particles, you can just sum over the gravitational field of each individual particle, and that is guaranteed to yield you the correct answer (within Newtonian gravity).

---

$^1$ As a disclaimer, I did not focus on being precise on my statements about GR in this answer, but rather on giving a handwaving explanation of effects that happen in GR. For example, there is a lot of difficulty in giving a precise sense to the words "gravitational potential energy" in GR, because one can't write a [stress-energy-momentum tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) for the gravitational field. Hence, be aware that the comments about GR on this answer are lacking detail, and meant only to provide some examples of how a non-linear gravitational field behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, gravity is a pairwise force and the equation determining the gravitational attraction between two particles is not affected by the introduction of a third particle. Gravity is linear in the sense that if we do have $N$ particles, then the force on the $i^{\text{th}}$ from the $N-1$ others is just

\begin{equation}
\textbf{F} = -\sum_{i\neq j}\frac{Gm_{i}m_{j}}{|\textbf{r}_{ij}|^{2}}\hat{\textbf{r}}_{ij}
\end{equation}

where $\textbf{r}_{ij} = \textbf{r}_{i} - \textbf{r}_{j}$, i.e. we just add up the forces from each particle.