# Regarding Page 224 Grififth Quantum Mechanics 3rd Edition

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, angular-momentum

[image]

[image]

With regards to the underlined text, I am unsure why $\frac{\hbar}{2}$ is the eigenvalues of the two eigenstates of $S_x$, and $\frac{i\hbar}{2}$, $\frac{-i\hbar}{2}$ to be the eigenvalues of the two eigenstates of $S_y$. If we look at the matrices $S_x$ and $S_y$, and solve for the eigenvalues, the eigenvalues should be identical to that of $S_z$, which would be $\frac{\hbar}{2}$ and $\frac{-\hbar}{2}$.

Comment: What about MathJax (4-months user) ???

Comment: Sorry? Which part requires more clarification?

Comment: You must realize  that you must stop posting questions with images of textbook pages  and use MathJax for editing.

Comment: Im currently learning based on textbook so I thought it would be more suitable if we follow the textbook's definition and context. The question at hand is also something I am unsure of based on certain parts of the book. I have use $$ to insert equations too so may I know which part is structured badly that I can improve on?

Comment: Also, do you happen to have an answer for my question? I happen to came across one of the question on spin that you answered not long ago.

Comment: [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you don't take the few minutes to properly format your question, don't expect us to answer your question.

Comment: Yep I referred to that very often when I post questions here, thanks for the info.

Comment: Sorry, do u meant the fractions? I will adjust accordingly

Comment: As @Frobenius already said: Stop using screen shots for equations and use MathJax instead. Further, if you want that another user is notified when you leave a comment, use an @ followed by the user name. BTW: You don't have to include every equation, just the most relevant ones such that the question is clear. You can then link to Wikipedia if you want to refer to the Pauli matrices, for example.

Comment: Oh I see, next time will take note not to do this.

Comment: What's wrong with doing this *now*?

Comment: @lel We do not mean the fractions. We mean *everything*. Whenever you want to quote a book, *type down the entire section you consider relevant of quoting*. If you believe two pages is too long for you, the person most interested in this post, to type down, it is also too long for us to read and think about in order to answer your question.

Comment: Sometimes I edit questions to adhere to these standards. If you'd like examples of how to convert from textbook to post format, you check the edit records for [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/713209/168783), [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/712754/168783), or [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/692240/168783).

Comment: Ok thank you so much, will do so in future questions.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, it is just that I figured out the answer myself, will change my method of asking questions and format properly for future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The states $|\uparrow\rangle,|\downarrow\rangle$ aren't eigenvectors of $S_x,S_y$ and the coefficients $\pm\tfrac{i\hbar}{2}$ aren't eigenvalues. My suggestion is that you should learn the basics of linear algebra, like how to do matrix multiplication and the definition of eigenvalue and eigenvector.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have noticed that it is simply matrix multiplication, I asked this question as I was confused of what the entries of the matrices actually meant. I now managed to understand that after some time. Im actually quite familiar with linear algebra, its just for this context it takes me some time to draw the relationship between the physical significance of the entries.